# Does Enabling the Bit Code will decrease the original size of Unity IOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, bitcode

I have been going through different posts regarding Bit Code option introduced in XCode. As i am creating a project in unity trying to reduce the over the air build size. According to most of the bit code post related to unity they ending up disabling it. my questions are

- **If i enable the bit code for unity project i know the addition bit
  code data will be stripped but does it will decrease the orignal size
  of Over-the-air build as right now i have an estimate universal
  Download size is 125 MB and i want it to be less then 100MB?**
- **Can i disable the bit code for a specific framework but enable for
  project?**

Unity Version : 5.3.5f1t
XCode : 7.2

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-3-x-build-size-increase-faq.383533/)
, bit code is specifically for App Store submission. And extra data will be stripped by App Store only. So I guess in all other cases like ad-hoc/OTA it will not reduce build size.

For your other question, you can use [PostProcessing](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.html) to change these settings.

Here is an example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
using System.IO;

public class BL_BuildPostProcess
{

    [PostProcessBuild]
    public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
    {

        if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS)
        {
            string projPath = path + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";

            PBXProject proj = new PBXProject();
            proj.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(projPath));

            string target = proj.TargetGuidByName("Unity-iPhone");

            proj.SetBuildProperty(target, "ENABLE_BITCODE", "false");

            File.WriteAllText(projPath, proj.WriteToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Other references:

[IL2CPP Build Size Optimizations](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/208412186-IL2CPP-build-size-optimizations)

[Bitcode Support In IOS & TvOS](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/209933103-Bitcode-Support-in-iOS-tvOS)

hope it helps :)